# ::before,::after擬似要素の親要素は？

Tags: css

下記HTMLで、itemクラスに「::before」「::after」を付与した時の、「各疑似要素」の「親要素」は、どこになるのでしょうか？

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='item'></div>";
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[5.12.3 The :before and :after pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#before-and-after)より

> The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert generated content before or after an element's content.

つまり、`::before`及び`::after`はitem要素のコンテンツの前後に要素を追加するものです。ですので、追加された要素の親要素は**item要素**となります。

関連する質問、[input[type=checkbox] に対して :before, :after 疑似要素が使えるのはChromeだけ？の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/17822/4236)も参照ください。